# Get name of key in key/value pair in JSON using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Say I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "title": "Title 1",
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "title": "Title 2",
    }
]
```

How would I return the set of key names that recur for each record? In this case, `ID, title`.

I tried:

```
$.getJSON('testing.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push(key +', ');
  });

  $('<p/>', {
     html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#content');
});
```

without success.

This is a JSON "database", and every "record" has the same keys. I just want a script that will tell me what the keys are, not test whether or not they occur in every entry.

Comment: so youve got an array of json objects.  you only want the shared keys right?  so if the first had another pair 'key':'val' but the second did not, you do not want that returned.  correcT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you an array of all the string properties that match across an array of objects. Is that what you are looking for?

```
$.getJSON('testing.json', function(data) {
    var propertiesThatExistInAll = getPropertiesThatExistInAll(data);
});


var getPropertiesThatExistInAll = function(arr) {
    var properties = $.map(data[0], function (prop, value) {
        return prop;
    });

    var propertiesThatExistInAll = [];

    $.each(properties, function (index, property) {
        var keyExistsInAll = true;

        // skip the first one since we know it has all the properties
        for (var i = 1, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (!data[i].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                keyExistsInAll = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (keyExistsInAll) {
            propertiesThatExistInAll.push(property);
        }
    });

    return propertiesThatExistInAll;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
items = [];
for (key in jsonobj) {
    if (!itemExists(items, key)) {
        items[items.length] = key
    }
}

function itemExists(items, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] == value) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, that will return items that exist in *any one* of the objects, not that exist in all. It's not entirely clear from your question if this is the solution you want.

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be made more efficient/concise, but the function below will do it.

```
var testJson = [ {'oi' : 1, 'arf': 2, 'foo' : 0}, {'oi': 5, 'arf': 7}];

function commonKeys(j)
{

    var fillUp = [];
    for(var i in j[0])
       fillUp.push(i);

    for(var i = 1; i < j.length; i++)
    {
       var cur = j[i]; var curArr = [];
       for (var i in cur) {curArr.push(i)};
       fillUp = fillUp.filter(function(x) {return (curArr.indexOf(x) != -1);});
    }

    return fillUp;
}

alert(commonKeys(testJson)); //oi,arf (not foo)
```