# Loop and get key/value pair for JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking to loop through a JSON array and display the key and value.

It should be a simplified version of the following post, but I don't seem to have the syntax correct: *[jQuery 'each' loop with JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030321/jquery-each-loop-with-json-array)*

I also saw the post *[Get name of key in key/value pair in JSON using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572708/get-name-of-key-in-key-value-pair-in-json-using-jquery)*, but it also seemed like lots of code for a simple activity.

This illustrates what I'm looking for (but it doesn't work):

```
var result = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
             //display the key and value pair
            alert(k + ' is ' + v);
        });
```

There is no mandatory jQuery requirement, but it is available. I can also restructure the JSON if it cuts down the required code.

Comment: You have to parse JSON to a JavaScript object first.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You have a string representing a JSON serialized JavaScript object. You need to deserialize it back to a JavaScript object before being able to loop through its properties. Otherwise you will be looping through each individual character of this string.

```
var resultJSON = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';
var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    //display the key and value pair
    alert(k + ' is ' + v);
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4GNW/).

Comment: Excellent.  I added var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON); and now it works.

Comment: @Darin how to get "index" value?

Answer (score 18):

```js
var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
for (var prop in obj) {
    alert(prop + " is " + obj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the values directly in case of one array like this:

```js
var resultJSON = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';
var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
result['FirstName']; // return 'John'
result['LastName'];  // return ''Doe'
result['Email']; // return 'johndoe@johndoe.com'
result['Phone'];  // return '123'
```

Answer (score 6):

The following should work for a JSON returned string. It will also work for an associative array of data.

```
for (var key in data)
     alert(key + ' is ' + data[key]);
```

Comment: `JSON` string has to be parsed into `JSON` object.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the JSON string and you can loop through the keys.

```js
var resultJSON = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';
var data = JSON.parse(resultJSON);

for (var key in data)
{
    //console.log(key + ' : ' + data[key]);
    alert(key + ' --> ' + data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and perfect solution for this issue:

I tried the jQuery with the Ajax success responses, but it doesn't work so I invented my own and finally it works!

[Click here to see the full solution](http://www.ac-base.org/javascript-get-json-value-by-key.html)

```
var rs = '{"test" : "Got it perfect!","message" : "Got it!"}';
eval("var toObject = "+ rs + ";");
alert(toObject.message);
```