# Struts2 Json plugin response customization

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have some bean with properties.
And json response is e.g.

```
bean:[{"id":"1", "name":"Jack", "lastname":"Poter"}]
```

Is there any ways in struts-json-plugin to convert response like this?

```
bean:[{"id":"id", "value":"1"}, {"id":"name", "value":"Jack"},...]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861032/loop-and-get-key-value-pair-for-json-array-using-jquery

Comment: return List<MyBean> ?

Comment: Return a: "List<Map> bean;" You'll need to manually create the correct layout (probably in execute).