# Filter a multidimensional json array by specific element with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json array:

```
{"0":  
   {"ChkSystem":
      {"id":"847",
       "item":"1",
       "fase":"#FE99CC",
       "description":"some info.",
       "image_path":"",
       "pm_id":"461",
       "main_systems_id":"1"
      }
   },
 "1":
   {"ChkSystem":
      {"id":"846",
       "item":"1",
       "fase":"#FE99CC",
       "description":"some data",
       "image_path":"",
       "pm_id":"461",
       "main_systems_id":"2"
      }
   },
"2":
  {"ChkSystem":
     {"id":"856",
      "item":"2",
      "fase":"#FE99CC",
      "description":"some data.",
      "image_path":"",
      "pm_id":"461",
      "main_systems_id":"2"
     }
  }
}
```

How can I filter it by `"main_systems_id"` with jquery?
The problem is the key is variable (`"0"`, `"1"` and so on) and in other posts that I had read that key is always the same.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: filter it how exactly ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why you use `"0", "1", "2"` object properties instead of using an Array of objects? Array is already indexed.

Comment: Hi @adeneo, for example posted above, I want all `"ChkSystem"` arrays where `"main_systems_id"` are equal to `"2"`

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan the array is in this form because is a php array generated by a cakephp query

Comment: @Efraín if your cakephp query was setup by a human... he was most probably in love...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a tool like [lodash](http://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) is more suited for something of this nature.

However should you really want to do it with jQuery:

```
function filterByMainSystemsId (object, value) {

  // The real meat of the solution, you can use this directly if you want.
  return $.map(object, function (item, key) { 

      // this is where the check is done
      if (item.ChkSystem.main_systems_id === value) {

        // if you want the index or property "0", "1", "2"... etc.
        // item._index = key;

        return item; 
      }
    });
  };
}

var object = /* ... your object goes here ... */;
var array = filterByMainSystemsId(object, "2") // [ { ... }, { ... } ]
```

I agree however, this should be an array and not an object, but things like elasticsearch and other tools make this hard and I can understand that.

Comment: Hi @Nijikokun thank for your answer, your code work perfectly but how can I do to get the object in plain object? I mean the form I posted in my question `{{...}}`

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle showing how you could do this here http://jsfiddle.net/Nijikokun/J8A68/ instead of returning the array from $.map, just add each item to an object and return the object instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array, but an object, containing sub objects. This would be the code for a json array:

```
[
{"ChkSystem":
      {"id":"847",
       "item":"1",
       "fase":"#FE99CC",
       "description":"some info.",
       "image_path":"",
       "pm_id":"461",
       "main_systems_id":"1"
      }
   },
   {"ChkSystem":
      {"id":"846",
       "item":"1",
       "fase":"#FE99CC",
       "description":"some data",
       "image_path":"",
       "pm_id":"461",
       "main_systems_id":"2"
      }
   },
  {"ChkSystem":
     {"id":"856",
      "item":"2",
      "fase":"#FE99CC",
      "description":"some data.",
      "image_path":"",
      "pm_id":"461",
      "main_systems_id":"2"
     }
  }
]
```

but you can also loop through json objects (key value pairs) and furthermore filter them. See [StackOverflow: loop and get key/value pair for JSON array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7861032/3346612)