# Jquery code to obtain the key name of a json data

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json data

```
jobs = [{
    "firstname": "myname"
}, {
    "place": "myplace"
}]
```

from this how can i print the key names `"firstname"` and `"place"`

```
$.each(jobs, function (key, value) {
    var name = value.firstname

});
```

what i want is in the output i have to print `firstname : myname` and `place : myplace`.*I dont want to hard code* `firstname` and `place`.i need to get it from json data itself.How it is possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572708/get-name-of-key-in-key-value-pair-in-json-using-jquery?rq=1 check this you will get idea how to do this

Comment: @Psl , See my answer. Edited it so that you dont have to hard-code first name n place. It will get it from json

Answer (score 1):

Use `for in` like

```
jobs.forEach(function(item){
    for(key in item){
        console.log(key);
        console.log(item[key])
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgBKW/

```
jobs = [{"firstname": "myname"}, {"place": "myplace"}];

$.each(jobs, function(key, value){
    $.each(value, function(key, value){
        console.log(key, value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var key= $.map(jobs , function(k,v){
    return k;
});
```

now key is array of key name

```
var value= $.map(jobs , function(k,v){
    return v;
});
```

now value is array of value name

now you can use this value as your desire way.....

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$.each(jobs, function (key, value) {
   for(index in value)
   {
       alert(index);
       alert(value[index]);
   }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/ybNem/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jQuery for that.

```
var jobs = [{
    "firstname": "myname"
}, {
    "place": "myplace"
}]

for(var i=0; item=jobs[i]; i++) {
    for(var prop in item) {
        console.log(prop + ": " + item[prop]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery required. Using `Object.keys`

```
var jobs = [{
    "firstname": "myname"
}, {
    "place": "myplace"
}]

jobs.forEach(function(job) {
    Object.keys(job).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key + ':' + job[key]);
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fQSEv/)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$.each(jobs, function(key,value ) { 
   console.log(key+" : "+value);
});
```